# Is there none numeric way to find the value of $x$?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Lets say I have the givens $$x=1, \quad y=75.0635 \pm4.10915$$
$$x=2,\quad  y=80.2912 \pm 7.76671$$
$$x=3, \quad y=98.2725 \pm 5.76051$$
$$x=4, \quad y=125.963 \pm 7.15494$$
$$x=5, \quad y=125.728 \pm 9.08732$$
$$x=6,\quad  y=128.012 \pm 10.0569$$
$$x=7, \quad y=140.672 \pm 7.51568$$

I have been asked to calculate $x=7.5$?

I was wandering if there is a way to solve the problem without using python or any other coding program

Comment: @Michal how can I do that when I have those uncertainties on $y$?

Comment: Search for something like linear / nonlinear regression.

Anyway you will have to create a model that depends on your data, the more data you have the better model can be. Haveing a model you will be able to calculate $x$.

You will se that it is a machine learing problem so I don't see any sense of calculating it manually.